# Does django transaction.non_atomic works in management scripts?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to update every entry in a single transaction. For that reason I wrote following management script:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
help = 'perform health check on all instances'

def printit(self):
    print('commited...')

@transaction.non_atomic_requests
def handle(self, *args, **options):

    # perform health check and data collection on all known servers
    print('Performing health checks...')
    for instance in Instance.objects.all():
        with transaction.atomic():
            instance.collect_stats()
            transaction.on_commit(self.printit)
```

In the documentation @transaction.non_atomic_requests can be activated for views. Does this option effect also management scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will run `collect_stats` for each instance in its own transaction, whether or not you use `transaction.non_atomic_requests`.

`transaction.non_atomic_requests` tells Django's view handler [not to use a transaction for the view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fc0fa72ff4cdbf5861a366e31cb8bbacd44da22d/django/core/handlers/base.py#L312). Your handle method isn't a view, it isn't run by Django's view handler, so the decorator won't have any effect.